# C++11 Aggregate initialization of private member, is it correct?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, aggregate-initialization

Is it correct to initialize private member through aggregate initialization while passing it as a parameter into owner's class function? Just look at code below.

```
class A {
  struct S {
    int t, u;
  };
public:
  void f(const S& s) {}  
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f({1, 2}); // correct?
  return 0;
}
```

I checked standard and nets and it seems that there is no exact answer. Looks like mechanics are as follows:
* braced initializer is public thing and thus user doesn't violate access restrictions.
* implicit conversion from initializer into "S" is internal for "S" and thus also fine for compiler.

The question is, whether there is some reference in standard, draft or at least cppreference with the description of this behaviour?

Comment: It's fine. But if you want answers with quotes from the C++ standard then please add the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy: `A` is not an aggregate because of the `private` struct.

Comment: Suggest you make it a `f(S)` to not cloud this question with the question of the creation of a temporary.

Comment: @P.W, but "S" is an aggregate, isn't it?

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy: Yes, IMO this should work.

Comment: @einpoklum, some times it's out of your power :-), I'm working with an open source code, and met public method, which takes a private member struct as a parameter. And currently I'm at fork, whether to fire a bug, or to accept existing way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct. The only thing private about `S` is the name. Access control only controls access through the name ([[class.access]p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#4.sentence-1)). So you could use a type trait to get the type of `S` for example through `f`'s type ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/EltWbK)).

So, it is allowed because there is no restriction [[dcl.init.agg]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr) that prohibits initializing "private" types.

There is also [a note](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#5.sentence-2), found by @StephaDyatkovskiy.

Comment: But how can this not contradict the meaning of "private"? Can you quote that perhaps?

Comment: @einpoklum Does [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#4.sentence-1) help clear it up? It might counter intuitive but that is how it works: Only when you name the type is access controlled applied.

Comment: Somewhat. It's not obvious that initializing an object does not involve knowing its type / type's name. Also, put that in the answer please; and note my answer.

Comment: @Rakete1111, following your references I have found exact answer: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#5.sentence-2
Could you may be edit your answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @einpoklum Do you suppose that you can't use the STL with your own private types?

Answer (score -1):

#### It doesn't matter whether it's officially valid; you should avoid this corner case.

I would claim that "is it valid C++" is the wrong question here.

When you look at a piece of code and, try as you might, you can't decide whether it should be valid C++ or not; and you know it's going to be some corner case depending on the exact wording of the standard - it's usually a good idea not to rely on that corner case, either way. Why? Because other people will get confused too; they will waste time trying to figure out what you meant; they will go look it up in the standard - or worse, not look it up, and make invalid assumptions; and they will be distracted from what they actually need to focus on.

So, with this code, I would ask myself: "Is type `S` really private? Does outside code really not need to know about it?"

If the answer is "Yes, it is" - then I would change `f`, to take the parameters for an S constructor (and forward them to the ctor):

```
void f(int t, int u) { S {t, u}; /* etc. etc. */ }
```

If the answer is "No, code calling `f()` can know that it's passing an `S` reference" - then I would make `S` public.

Comment: you're super-correct in everything you say, but only if you're boss of all the code you're working with.

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy: I see what you mean, but: 1. Other people reading this question do not have that problem. 2. It's also advise you can pass on to whoever owns the code.